# Adding button to Tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Okay, so I am trying to add a button to a table view cell. My table view cell has an image, label and a button. I set the button to be hidden in storyboard. Now I'm trying to show the button if the label text is truncated, I set the number of lines on my label to 3 in storyboard. It works but when I scroll up and down, somehow some cells with the label text  not truncated shows a button. Why?

This is how my cell file looks atm.

```
class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var itemImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var itemTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemDetailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var moreButton: UIButton!

var item: Item? {
    didSet {
        configureCell()
    }
}

private func configureCell() {
    guard let item = item else { return }
    itemImageView.image = item.image
    itemTitleLabel.text = item.name
    itemDetailLabel.text = item.description


    if itemDetailLabel.isTruncated  {
        moreButton.isHidden = false
    } else {
        moreButton.isHidden = true
    }
}

extension UILabel {
var isTruncated: Bool {

    guard let labelText = text else {
        return false
    }

    let labelTextSize = (labelText as NSString).boundingRect(
        with: CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude),
        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [.font: font],
        context: nil).size

    return labelTextSize.height > bounds.size.height
}
}
```

This is how my cellForRowAt looks like.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as? ItemCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    let item = categories[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]

    cell.item = item

    print("Name: \(item.name)\nSection: \(indexPath.section)\nRow: \(indexPath.row)\nisTruncated: \(cell.itemDetailLabel.isTruncated)\n")



    return cell
}
```

Comment: Show your `cellForRowAt` function, but essentially cells are reused so you must ensure that the cell state is set properly based on the your data model.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have added the method. Now should I add a property in my item model? If so, how would I be able to check if the item details text are going to be truncated?